# Parse Json to grid

Tags: c#, json, serialization, grid, json.net

I'm trying to serialize this json:

```
{
  "tickets": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Probleem met windows",
      "description": "Kan geen programma installeren.",
      "user_id": 1,
      "subject_id": 1,
      "status_id": 1,
      "status": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Afgerond"
      },
      "subject": {
        "id": 1,
        "subject": "Hardware"
      },
      "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "company": "test",
        "role_id": 2,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": "2016-09-16 20:45:30"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And show it within a datagrid like this:

```
  private void getTickets()
        {
            try
            {
                string urlName = "tickets";
                string method = "GET";
                string json = null;
                HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                Ticket data = null;

                RestClient client = RequestClient.makeClient();
                MakeRequest request = new MakeRequest(null, null, urlName, method);

                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request.exec());

                statusCode = response.StatusCode;
                json = response.Content;
                data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ticket>(json);

                if ((int)statusCode == 200)
                {
                    gridTickets.DataSource = data;
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("error");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

So if I debug there is a correct response. But the data is not loaded correctly in the grid. What could be wrong here?

[image]

--EDIT--

Ticket:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TicketSystem
{
    class Ticket
    {
        public int id;
        public string title;
        public string description;
        public int user_id;
        public int subject_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no code generating the Grid.

Comment: What's the schema of the `Ticket` class. Paste complete code for understanding the issue.

Comment: Can I see the code on Grid part? My best guess is to check data type and nullable values (e.g. created_at) and how do grid handle them.

Comment: I've added the Ticket class above!

Comment: And added the grid aswel.

Comment: De-serialization of Json into `Ticket` class would have issue they are not matching

Comment: Sorry about that. Just changed that. But that's not the problem.

Comment: You are de-serializing a `Ticket` object from `Json` that contain `IEnumerable<Ticket>`, for grid binding you need `IEnumerable<Ticket>`

Comment: Also still can't see the `Grid` binding code

Comment: The binding is there: `gridTickets.DataSource = data;` could you perhaps post an example?

Comment: Check the example underneath

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can be :

```
   var json = "{\r\n  \"tickets\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"id\": 1,\r\n      \"title\": \"Probleem met windows\",\r\n      \"description\": \"Kan geen programma installeren.\",\r\n      \"user_id\": 1,\r\n      \"subject_id\": 1,\r\n      \"status_id\": 1,\r\n      \"status\": {\r\n        \"id\": 1,\r\n        \"name\": \"Afgerond\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"subject\": {\r\n        \"id\": 1,\r\n        \"subject\": \"Hardware\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"user\": {\r\n        \"id\": 1,\r\n        \"name\": \"test\",\r\n        \"email\": \"test@gmail.com\",\r\n        \"company\": \"test\",\r\n        \"role_id\": 2,\r\n        \"created_at\": null,\r\n        \"updated_at\": \"2016-09-16 20:45:30\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}";
   var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
   DataGrid.ItemsSource = data.tickets;
```

Comment: +1, Interesting, though I always prefer to work with typed entities, especially when it is known, as dynamic has a huge scope of run time only issues